# Rails 3: Where to store shared methods for models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I have a method "random_password" that I'd like to be able to access from multiple models in my rails 3 project. I'm just wondering what the convention is for where to store it & how to provide access to it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need a module. This is shared and can be used by multiple models. They are typically placed in /lib.